# How do I add a retry option to a function in Python?

Tags: python

Pretty new to Python, trying to create a simple login system here (has to be done this way). I've already defined a user() function which asks for the username and checks its validity. This function starts by calling the user function. Here is the main part:

```
user() 

    if user in userlist:
        while True:
            pass = raw_input("Enter password, or X to retry: ")
            if pass == 'X':
                break
            if userlist[user] == pass:
                break
            else:
                print "Invalid password."
```

I want the function to loop back to asking for username input if X is entered. The rest of it works fine but as it stands, entering X just ends the function and doesn't loop it back to the start. Is this just not possible or can I rewrite it to work? I assume I'd need to include user() into the loop but I've encountered various errors while trying.

Comment: You might want to avoid the variable name as `"pass"`, it will shadow the python built-in keyword `pass`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You intentionally say to exit the loop if the user enters `X` by using the `break` statement. That's why the loop is exiting. Instead of `break` use `continue`.

```
if password == 'X':
    continue
```

This will start the loop over again at the top.

As another user notes, you can't use `pass` as a variable name. The code you posted clearly isn't the code you're actually running. Anyway, I've assumed that you really used the name `password`.

Comment: A few of my variable names were long and not clear. I was planning on tidying them up if I got it working but thought I might as well do it when posting it on here. I didn't realise `pass` wouldn't work!

Comment: Anyway, I've done as you said and I've restructured the code slightly. It works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use pass as a variable name because it clobbers the builtin `pass`. What you want is

```
if passwd == 'X':
    continue #restart at top of loop
```

Comment: Actually the user's code won't even run because of this. (It doesn't clobber the built-in; `pass` is a keyword.) Good catch.

Comment: derp. It is indeed a keyword. Thanks for correcting me :)

Comment: I didn't even notice myself, had to edit my answer! As I said, good catch.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do:

```
if password == 'X':
    continue #restarts loop at while
```